# Does AIX have some kind of Memory based storage engine(solution)?

Tags: aix

I was wondering if there are any solutions or engines that can be used as memory based storage (memcached like) for AIX

Comment: I've compiled memcached for AIX.   And redis.   And tokyocabinet.  Probably some others as well.  Would those not work for you?    AIX has nothing "built in".

Comment: I see... I am at the level of planning atm so... I was just wondering if it was possible or not. It seems possible from your answer Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've compiled memcached for AIX.  And redis. And tokyocabinet. Probably some others as well.

AIX has nothing "built in".